# C++ Template deduction while calling a template function

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

`FastDelegate` refers to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx, but I don't think it is related.

I have code like following, and got error.

```
#include <FastDelegate.h>


using namespace fastdelegate;

template <typename T>
T Getter() {}

template <typename T>
void Setter(T) {}

template <typename T>
class Prop
{
public:
    typedef FastDelegate0<T> Getter;
    typedef FastDelegate1<T> Setter;

    Prop(Getter getter, Setter setter) :
        m_Getter(getter), m_Setter(setter)
    {

    }

private:
    Getter m_Getter;
    Setter m_Setter;
};

template <typename T>
inline Prop<T>* MakeProp(FastDelegate0<T> getter, FastDelegate1<T> setter)
{
    return new Prop<T>(getter, setter);
}

static int Target = 0;
int main()
{
    FastDelegate0<int> fdGetter(Getter<int>);
    Prop<int>* c = MakeProp(fdGetter, Setter<int>);
    // ^^^^ error: no matching function for call to 'MakeProp'
}
```

If changed the `main()` to:

```
int main()
{
    FastDelegate0<int> fdGetter(Getter<int>);
    FastDelegate1<int> fdSetter(Setter<int>);
    Prop<int>* c = MakeProp(fdGetter, fdSetter); // It works.
}
```

or:

```
int main()
{
    FastDelegate0<int> fdGetter(Getter<int>);
    Prop<int>* c = MakeProp<int>(fdGetter, Setter<int>); // It works, too.
}
```

I think, `MakeProp()` should get the `T` from fdGetter (which is `int`, than called the contructor of `FastDelegate1<int>` automatically. But it did not. Why?

P.S. I would like to save the getter and setter in `Prop`, any suggestion for this approach is welcome. Maybe it is bad to copy the instance of FastDelegate* during passing arguments in function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888082/implicit-conversion-not-happening (you are in fact trying to mix template deduction with implicit conversion).

Comment: @alexisdm Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I think to compiler get enough info to make the implicit conversion. Thank you for fingering out it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Prop<int>* c = MakeProp(FastDelegate0<int>(Getter<int>), FastDelegate1<int>(Setter<int>));
```

?

`Setter<int>` cannot be converted to `FastDelegate1<T>`!

Comment: To be honest, I have gotten the answer from the "question" in @alexisdm 's comment. But thank you all the same.