# I have a matrix class like below:

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <size_t M, size_t N, typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix<M, N, T> operator +(const Matrix<M, N, T>& B) const;
    template <size_t P> Matrix<M,P,T> operator*(const Matrix<N, P, T>& B) const;
    template <typename T2> operator T2() const;  

private:
  T __x[M][N];
};
```

The body has written fine, and everything works well. When I define two Matrices as below:

```
Matrix < 10, 10, int> m1;
Matrix < 10, 10, float> m2;

m1 + m2;  // OK
m1 * m2;  // error: no match for 'operator*' in 'm1 * m2'
```

The addition works well, because an implicit casting has performed on it, but for the multiplication of different value types, an error occurs.

```
error: no match for 'operator*' in 'm1 * m2'
```

Any idea ?!

Comment: How is this a PHP or MySQL question?

Comment: Did I left out some classes of php or wtf!?

Comment: Can you please post the entire error-message you get?

Comment: There is no such thing as "implicit casting".

Comment: [Here's the testcase.](http://codepad.org/m5eomdTf)

Comment: Aren't identifiers starting with double underscore reserved?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: More than that; any identifier *containing* an double underscore is reserved.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888082/implicit-conversion-not-happening) has a similar problem. The reason for you error is that implicit conversions are not considered when deducing template arguments. Since your multiplication operator is a function-template, and you call without explicitly providing the parameter, the compiler tries to deduce the argument type and fails. To demonstrate, if you explicitly provide the parameter `P`, it compiles:

```
m1.operator*<10>(m2);
```

To fix the problem, you could make the value-type of the right-hand-side a template-argument too:

```
template <size_t P, typenmame T2> 
Matrix<M,P,T> operator*(const Matrix<N, P, T2>& B) const;
```

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: It is not a function-template, so no arguments have to be deduced.

Comment: OK, true; but then the `T` in `op*` is not deduced either.

Comment: Right. I am not sure, but the error-message does not actually say that the mismatch is due to `T` - it could be due to `P` (or the inability to deduce it).

Comment: To demonstrate, [it compiles](http://codepad.org/f8VapC1T) when explicitly providing `P` (ignore the linker-errors - they happen after successful compilation).

Comment: `P` seems trivially deducible to me (and, yes, I know what happens when you don't define a function, thanks :P). Perhaps the issue _is_ conversion of `T`, although `T` is not deduced, but because the call is via a function template and _instantiation_ does not occur implicitly due to no exact matching template. Or summat.

Comment: @Tomalak: this answer is correct. Implicit conversions are not considered when deducing. See this simple example: http://www.ideone.com/c59AZ

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I never said it's not correct. I am trying to understand _why_ it's correct. And I do not believe that your example is a direct analogy; `T` is _not_ a deduced argument here. Praps conversion doesn't happen when _any_ argument must be deduced, even if the deduction is not on the value to be converted.